# Design Tab not displaying correctly (Content is flipped)

Tags: android, xml

On Design tab (With no issues within the xml text) of my activity, content is shown correctly, but when I run an AVD everything is flipped:

Design tab view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXrzj.png

AVD view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4oIh.png

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NewGameMenu">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/disSeek"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar.Discrete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:max="10"
        android:progress="1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:text="Left side Text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/disSeek"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is your emulator set up for a RTL language, such as Arabic or Hebrew?

Comment: @CommonsWare THANKS SO MUCH!! Force RTL was on in developer settings... 